# Notebook Instance Lifecycle Config for Notebook Instance took longer than 5 minutes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a notebook using Sagemaker Lifecycle configuration but I am running into timeout issues. I went through blogs online on how to run scripts/codes that take >5 mins.

Figured out that using `nohup` and `&` would put the process in the background to complete. However I am running into timeout issues and havent been able to figure out why.

Below is that script and error I am receiving

```
set -e
ENVIRONMENT=python3
NOTEBOOK_FILE="/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/mynotebook.ipynb"
AUTO_STOP_FILE="/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/auto-stop.py"
IDLE_TIME=300 # 5minute

echo "<>Activating conda env"
echo "<>PWD: $PWD"
source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT"

echo "<>Installing packages"
pip install cloudscraper==1.2.58 bs4 
pip install pandas 
pip install boto3 s3fs 

echo "<>Starting notebook"
nohup jupyter nbconvert "$NOTEBOOK_FILE" --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3 --to notebook --inplace  --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 --execute &

echo "<>Decativating conda env"
source deactivate
# PARAMETERS

echo "<>Fetching the autostop script"
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/autostop.py

echo "<>Starting the SageMaker autostop script in cron"
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python $PWD/autostop.py --time $IDLE_TIME --ignore-connections") | crontab -
"
```

Error -

> Failure reason Notebook Instance Lifecycle Config
> 'arn:aws:sagemaker:ap-south-1:588770669142:notebook-instance-lifecycle-config/web-scraping-lifecycle'
> for Notebook Instance
> 'arn:aws:sagemaker:ap-south-1:588770669142:notebook-instance/web-scraping-routines-lambda'
> took longer than 5 minutes. Please check your CloudWatch logs for more
> details if your Notebook Instance has Internet access.

Answer (score 0):

try with this, this is working at my end

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html "$NOTEBOOK_FILE" --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3 ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 --execute
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).